# How to understand 'The this inside a static block refers to the constructor object of the class'?

Tags: javascript

[MDN-Static initialization blocks:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks#description)

> The this inside a static block refers to the constructor object of the class

I think it's incorrect. The 'this' keyword refers to the class itself, not the constructor object of the class.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {}
  static {
    console.log(this); // class A {}
    console.log(this === A); // true
  }
}
```

Maybe I misunderstood, I don't know what 'constructor object' means or where it comes from. It's the first time I've heard this term. I only know that A is a class, and in this example, 'this' refers to A.

Comment: The wording is weird; the term "constructor object" means `A` in your example. It's the object you invoke with `new` to make a new instance of the class. Note that `A.constructor` is `Function`, not the "constructor" method of the class.

Comment: 'constructor object' a synonym? Are 'constructor object' and 'class' the same concept?

Comment: I think (well, I am guessing) that they wrote "constructor object" and not "constructor function" because class constructors are not *exactly* functions. They look and act like functions but they are not callable the way you can call ordinary functions. In traditional JavaScript, they were plain functions, but now with `class` syntax, they are not.  Thus, a "constructor object" is the value  you use after `new`, and the code for the "constructer" class property is the code that is evaluated when you do that.

Comment: `[value].constructor` will refer to its creator object and not local object because `class` is `function` so `A.constructor` will point to `Function`

Comment: @Pointy I'd guess that the phrasing was chosen to emphasise that the constructor (function) is an object - like almost anything in OOP

Comment: "*I only know that A is a class*" - how do you define "class"? How do you define "constructor"? If someone writes `new x()`, what do you call `x`?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what "constructor object" means

It's synonymous for "the class object" or "the class itself" here. `A` is the object that you use to construct instances of the class using `new A`, it is the constructor - and at the same time, it is representing the entire class, including its `.prototype` property and the methods thereon.

The qualifier "object" is superfluous here (or used for emphasis?), everything that we talk about in the context of classes is an object, including the constructor (function).